# Android Application Installation

Tags: android

I am new in android and I have develop an application in android but the issue is when i install it on my device it shows me 2 icons one is working and other one says that `receipt organizer has been stopped unexpectedly`.
Kindly let me know how i can get out of this rid ?
Is it some kind of code error or problem in the `manifest or properties` ?
Also one more question  now my api level is set to 18 if i set it to previous version then the functionality will not get disturbed right ?
So let me know if any one can help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your manifest file. Your manifest file should have only one activity that has the LAUNCHER in the intent filter.

Choose your main activity (which should have this intent filter), and delete the intent filters from the other activity. after that, you should see only one application icon.

Comment: <receiver
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>